# How can I switch urls for src, mouseover and mouseout - using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, src, rollover

I have product list of around 90 items with images which have src, mouseover, mouseout attributes. 
Basically mouseout src is same as image src. 
Rollover works fine, however I would like to flip current rollover functionality.

e.g: default image (before hover) should be the current rollover image, and rollover image (when hovered) should be the default image.

**Current Code:**

```
 <div class="item">
    <a href="productURL"class="product-image">
        <img id="product-collection-image"
            src="http://imageUrl-1xxxxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name"
            onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-1xxxxxxx.jpg';" 
            onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-1xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
    </a>
 </div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="productURL"class="product-image">
        <img id="product-collection-image"
            src="http://imageUrl-2xxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name"
            onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-2xxxxxxx.jpg';" 
            onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-2xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="productURL"class="product-image">
        <img id="product-collection-image"
            src="http://imageUrl-3xxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name"
            onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-3xxxxxxx.jpg';" 
            onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-3xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**Desired Result:**

```
 <div class="item">
    <a href="productURL"class="product-image">
        <img id="product-collection-image"
            src="http://imageUrl-over-1xxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name"
            onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-1xxxxxxxxx.jpg';" 
            onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-1xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
    </a>
 </div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="productURL"class="product-image">
        <img id="product-collection-image"
            src="http://imageUrl-over-2xxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name"
            onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-2xxxxxxx.jpg';" 
            onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-2xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="productURL"class="product-image">
        <img id="product-collection-image"
            src="http://imageUrl-over-3xxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name"
            onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-3xxxxxxx.jpg';" 
            onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-3xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This is what I currently have:

```
var items = $(".item a");
var imgSrc = items.children('img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).get();

var hoverSrc = items.children('img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('onmouseover').slice();
}).get();

    console.log(hoverSrc);
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with javascript, rather than changing whatever is generating this markup?

Comment: @Taplar I want to change this functionality only for one category, other categories should remain default.

Comment: And you can't make that change server side?

Comment: @Taplar All categories are generated from CMS and have the same code.

Comment: Alright, just taking care of that question, :)

Comment: @Taplar much appreciated

Comment: BTW, your images are repeating ids.  That's invalid markup from a web standards stand point.

Comment: Actually each image has a unique id <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>". Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.item .product-image img').each(function(index, image){
  //get the over logic
  var mouseover = image.getAttribute('onmouseover');
  //get the out logic
  var mouseout = image.getAttribute('onmouseout');
  
  //execute the over logic so it will change the src to be the over url
  image.onmouseover();
  //swap the over and out logic for each other
  image.setAttribute('onmouseover', mouseout);
  image.setAttribute('onmouseout', mouseover);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <a href="productURL" class="product-image">
    <img id="product-collection-image" src="http://imageUrl-1xxxxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name" onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-1xxxxxxx.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-1xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <a href="productURL" class="product-image">
    <img id="product-collection-image" src="http://imageUrl-2xxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name" onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-2xxxxxxx.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-2xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <a href="productURL" class="product-image">
    <img id="product-collection-image" src="http://imageUrl-3xxxxxxx.jpg" alt="product name" onmouseover="this.src='http://imageUrl-over-3xxxxxxx.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='http://imageUrl-3xxxxxxx.jpg';" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Much appreciated!